# How to replace any null in pyspark df with value from the below row, same column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

Let's say I have a pyspark DF:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| val1     | val1B    |
| null     | val2B    |
| val2     | null     |
| val3     | val3B    |
```

Can someone help me with replacing any null value in any column (for the whole df) with the value right below it? So the final table should look like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | val1B |
| val2 | val2B |
| val2 | val3B |
| val3 | val3B |

How could this be done? Can I get a code demo if possible? Thank you!

All I've really gotten through is counting all the row nums and creating a condition to find the row nums with all of the null values. So I'm left with a table like this:

| Column A | Column B | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | val2B | 2 |
| val2 | null | 3 |

But I don't think this step is needed. I'm stuck as to what to do.

Comment: Usually null values are replaced with default values, or pre computed values like averages, or median etc.
You can fill null values using this [fillna] method
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list squares to coalesce each column with the lead window function. Code below

```
df.select(*[coalesce(col(x),lead(x).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy( monotonically_increasing_id()))).alias(x) for x in df.columns]).show()


+--------+--------+
|Column A|Column B|
+--------+--------+
|    val1|   val1B|
|    val2|   val2B|
|    val2|   val3B|
|    val3|   val3B|
+--------+--------+
```